# Extension Method to Remove all weekends inside the DateTime.Now C#

Tags: c#, datetime

Good day,

I'm trying to create an extension method that removes the Weekends inside the datetime. But it doesn't work properly.

So far, here's my code

```
public static class DatetimeExtension
{
    public static int RemoveWeekends(this DateTime date)
    {
        if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        {
            date = date.AddDays(-1);
        }

        return date.Day;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use it here `DateTime.Now.RemoveWeekends() - 2;`

any help please?

Comment: So what if its Sunday you are setting it to Saturday?

Comment: It is unclear what it is you are actually tying to do. Give some more context

Comment: What means *remove*? Change date to last working day?

Comment: You can also rename to better describe what you are doing. Like `EnsureWorkDay`

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that it doesn't work properly because if the day is *Sunday* it returns *Saturday* as you're only ever deducting one day. One alternative approach you could take is:

```
public static class DatetimeExtension
{
    public static int RemoveWeekends(this DateTime date)
    {
        while(date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        {
            date = date.AddDays(-1);
        }

        return date.Day;
    }
}
```

i.e. Look at the date and keep moving back by 1 day until such time as the `DayOfWeek` is not Saturday or Sunday.

If you run it with this test:

```
var date = new DateTime(2019, 01, 13); // this is Sunday 13th January 2019

var result = date.RemoveWeekends();
```

It should return `11` which is Friday, i.e. tomorrow.

This is a little inefficient though, as for a Sunday it'll result in `AddDays` being called twice, resulting in two new instances of `DateTime` being created. A version that doesn't have this overhead would be:

```
public static int RemoveWeekends(this DateTime date)
{
    switch (date.DayOfWeek)
    {
        case DayOfWeek.Saturday:
            date = date.AddDays(-1);
            break;
        case DayOfWeek.Sunday:
            date = date.AddDays(-2);
            break;
    }

    return date.Day;
}
```

Comment: but when I call that extension method, the day is still the same

Comment: it still doesn't exclude the days in weekend sir

Comment: @jsonGPPD, you'll need to be clearer about (a) how you're calling the code, (b) what value you're passing in, and (c) what you're expecting to see come out of the other end - I'd suggest that would be worthwhile editing into your question rather than adding as commentary here =)